# Remove all inline font related tags even if its within an inline style

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a DOM, and in this DOM, I have loaded an entire webpage's HTML. I want to remove all font-related tags, even if its within a style tag.

Comment: Of course you can do it manually ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pure Javascript function that'll convert any of a specified set of tags into a `<span>`:

```
function stripFonts(el, tags) {
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName in tags) {

        // replace the element with a span
        var old = el, el = document.createElement('span');
        old.parentNode.replaceChild(el, old);

        // and move the children
        while (old.hasChildNodes()) {
            el.appendChild(old.firstChild);
        }
    }

    // recursive test all of this node's children
    var child = el.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        child.removeAttribute('style');  // NB: removes *all* style attributes
        stripFonts(child, tags);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

var tags = { 'B': 1, 'FONT': 1, 'STRIKE': 1 };
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/4fBRQ/

Using a `<span>` simplifies the code because it maintains the original DOM tree, and avoids the need to collapse adjacent text nodes together.

Adding extra tags to be stripped is trivial.  It would need *some* additional work to handle font specific inline style tags, although removing *every* `style` attribute is easy, as shown here.

Answer (score 2):

```
     $("font").attr("face", "");
    $("*").css("font", "");
```

You Can clear the fact attr of font element and clear font feom all css in DOM using jQuery